# using Python 3.7, how to use of numpy complex with an array of values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, complex-numbers

I am new to Python, so I apologize ahead of time if this question is too  basic.

Say I have a complex value 50+ j(10 w), where w is an array of frequencies, for example,

```
import numpy as np

w=2*np.pi*np.linspace(1800e6,2400e6,100)
```

how do  I use **np.complex** to calculate the complex value for each value in the **w** array (or any other way to accomplish this)?

In Matlab, I could do

```
z = 50 + i.*w.*10
```

(although I don't think I would need to since everything else is a scalar in the equation, but this helps show what I want to do --element by element multiplication).

Anyway, when I try:

```
z=np.complex(50,10*w)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-a78f7e2cf118>", line 1, in <module>
    z=np.complex(50,10*w)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'
```

I appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Comment: Same as MATLAB, except you use `1j` instead of `i`: `z = 50 + 1j * w * 10`.  The docs for `np.complex` say it `Create a complex number` (**a** implies 1).  But it also shows the Python constructor, `(real + imag*1j)`.

Comment: thank you...the trick is to use *1j, not j, like I was trying.  Thank you.